# Matrix factorization using stochastic gradient descent

Tags: gradient-descent, matrix-decomposition, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am trying to approximate a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ using the following matrix factorization

$$A \approx \hat{A} = Z \Lambda^{-1}Z^T$$

where $\Lambda=\text{diag}(Z^T \mathbb{1})$ and $Z$ is sparse. I would like to use **stochastic gradient descent** (SGD) in order to achieve that

$$\arg \underset{\hat{A}}{\min} \| A - \hat{A} \|$$

So, basically, I would compute some entries of $A$ (because $A$ is a huge matrix) and use these to factorize the matrix. But I am not very sure about the way to do it.

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric? Note that $\hat A$ is. Which matrix norm are you using?

Comment: Yes $A$ is symmetric and the norm is spectral.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What is the context?

Comment: How do you want to enforce sparsity on Z? Are there extra penalty terms or constraints you haven't mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm goes like this:

1. Start with randomly initialized values of $Z$ and $\Lambda^{-1}$
2. Go through each value $A_{ij}$
3. Compute the gradient of $||A_{ij} - \hat{A}_{ij}||$
4. Update the parameters $Z, Z^T$ and $\Lambda^{-1}$ in the direction of the gradient using a step size $\eta$. It's a hyper-parameter and needs to be learned using cross validation.
   $Z_i = Z_i - \nabla(||A_{ij} - (Z_{ij}^2 \times \Lambda_{jj} \times Z_i)||)$

In step 3 you may want to add regularization to prevent overfitting. Take a look at the pseudo code on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Iterative_method).